# PhpStorm: syntax highlight excludes for default.phtml

Tags: php, intellij-idea, phpstorm

I have PhpStorm 2017.1. There is an error for syntax highlighting for `default.phtml` file:

[image]

`items.phtml` has 'php' icon near the file name, but `default.phtml` has 'gear' icon (configuration?). I know there is "Editor / File Types" settings in PhpStorm but I see no exclusions for "default.phtml":

[image]

How can I fix syntax highlighting exclusion for `default.phtml`?

Comment: Please check for `default.phtml` under **Text file** -- this is where such pattern would usually be present in such cases. **P.S.** Use one of the bundled GUI Themes to see original file type icons -- they help in identifying the issue. Right now you must be using custom theme installed as plugin (e.g. Afterglow Theme or Material UI Theme) -- if so -- such plugin must be disabled in order to change theme.

Comment: thanks, @LazyOne, it was just  Afterglow Theme plugin. Icons & formatting are restored after plugin was removed.